# Check on the new atavistic captcha

Tags: discussion

June 6, prompted with the captcha, I picked all the *Store Fronts* it failed, Huh? Then I picked all *Street Numbers*, it failed again, WTF? I worked them the same way I always did before.

Ah, a new captcha? Trying again, the images now change to show another image underneath that you have to continually go through until you have exhausted picking all the arguably responsive images from the 2-3 layers of images provided.

Is there really such a dire problem with bots or other non-humans hitting this site that a layered image captcha is necessary?

I get why this type of new and improved captcha could help, but if there isn't a compelling need for it, why do it? It's somewhat akin to the nebulous *Voter ID* laws pushed in red states.

You guys on meta-know best, if there is a need, keep it, but if not, it's really a bit annoying. I don't know if you guys can tweak captcha anymore, of if it is now a proprietary offering of some 3rd party site, but if you can, just a single layer of images seemed good enough. Those are difficult enough for the sight impaired.

Comment: The captcha is provided by Google; what they require changes based on your location and history, among other factors. I don't think we have a way to tell it to relax. And yes, the captcha itself is very necessary - but most legitimate users should very rarely hit it

Comment: @Undo Case in point, I for one have never hit the captcha.

Comment: I know I hit it once or twice a week. Not much, but whenever SO does whatever it does to expire a cookie or so. It's not bad, but after being in this area since before Mosaic, somethings just seem like answers in search of a problem. I figured, it was something out of SE's control. That says something too. Oh well, at least we know we just have to live with it, get better glasses, and still have a 50/50 chance choosing a door instead of a *"store front"*.

Comment: ".. since *before* Mosaic". Switchboard operators?

Comment: Oh, no, no, no.. [**Mosaic (web browser) **](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_(web_browser)) which became publicly available in ~91 and before which it would have been `ftp 151.101.1.69`.